# Confluent jdbc sink connector not working with json based topics and ms sql server target db

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Confluent jdbc sink connector not inserting data into ms SQL server 2016

The messages in my source topic are from a ms SQL server 2016 and serialized using the json serialized. My confluent version is 5.2. Target db is also ms SQL server 2016 and id used to connect to target has write permissions. Target table does not have any keys.
I renamed the old ms SQL jdbc driver and gave the latest version of ms provided ms SQL server jdbc driver. I restarted confluent connector service.

Source connector

```
{
  "name": " test-source-mssql-jdbc-bulk",
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
  "tasks.max": "10",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "header.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.SimpleHeaderConverter",
  "config.action.reload": "restart",
  "errors.retry.timeout": "0",
  "errors.tolerance": "none",
  "errors.log.enable": "true",
  "errors.log.include.messages": "true",
  "connection.url": "jdbc:sqlserver://test:112255;database=testdb;encrypt=false;trustServerCertificate=true;loginTimeout=30;",
  "connection.user": "testid",
  "connection.password": "********",
  "table.whitelist": "TEST_TABLE",
  "table.blacklist": "",
  "mode": "bulk",
  "table.types": "TABLE,VIEW",
  "poll.interval.ms": "600000",
  "topic.prefix": "TEST_PREFIX",
  "timestamp.delay.interval.ms": "10000"
}
```

Target

```
{
  "name": "test-sink-mssql-jdbc-bulk",
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
  "tasks.max": "10",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "header.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.SimpleHeaderConverter",
  "config.action.reload": "restart",
  "errors.retry.timeout": "0",
  "errors.tolerance": "none",
  "errors.log.enable": "true",
  "errors.log.include.messages": "true",
  "topics": [
    "TESTTOPIC_TEST_PREFIX "
  ],
  "errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name": "TEST_DLQ",
  "errors.deadletterqueue.context.headers.enable": "true",
  "connection.url": "jdbc:sqlserver://test:22222;database=testdb;encrypt=false;trustServerCertificate=true;loginTimeout=30;",
  "connection.user": "testid",
  "connection.password": "*********",
  "insert.mode": "insert",
  "table.name.format": "KafkaTables",
  "pk.mode": "none",
  "pk.fields": "",
  "auto.create": "true",
  "auto.evolve": "false",
  "max.retries": "1",
  "retry.backoff.ms": "3000"
}
```

I dont get any errors in confluent monitor when I start sink connector.just data is not written to target db.

Comment: Can you check your Kafka Connect worker log for errors, and edit your question to include any.

Comment: What is the name and  the location of the file (relative to the install root)

Comment: How are you running Kafka Connect? The log location will vary whether you're using a service, Confluent CLI, tar install, etc

Comment: I have configured kafka connect using the confluence monitor web site and have also started the sink connector from there

Comment: How did you deploy Confluent Platform?

Comment: Another team did. I turned on debug level logging for connect and seems that the jdbc sink connector is not taking the user I'd and password provided as there is error message that target db is asking for password.

Comment: Any idea why kafka connect jdbc sink connector is not taking the supplied db password in the sink configuration to connect to the db?